# use argparse to pass login to requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, argparse

I am trying to get argparse to pass login details from the command line to requests. But I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_no_output.py", line 811, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_no_output.py", line 733, in main
    write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_no_output.py", line 421, in write_data_to_confluence
    info = get_page_info(auth, pageid)
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances_no_output.py", line 416, in get_page_info
    r = requests.get(url, auth = auth)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 519, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
    self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
    r = auth(self)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

In my program I am going:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is a program that lists the servers in EC2')
parser.add_argument(
"-u",
"--user",
default = getpass.getuser(),
help = "Specify the username to log into Confluence")

parser.add_argument(
"-d",
"--password",
help = "Specify the user's password")
options = parser.parse_args()
html = 'hi'
pageid = 123456789
title = 'hello'
if options.password and options.user:
    user = options.user
    password = options.password
    auth = {user:password}
    write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title)

def write_data_to_confluence(auth, html, pageid, title):
    url = '{base}/{pageid}'.format(base = BASE_URL, pageid = pageid)
    r = requests.put(
        url,
        data = data,
        auth = auth,
        headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }
        )
```

How can I get `auth` to be in the right format for requests?

Comment: It's expected to be *callable*, as the error suggests - see e.g. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/#new-forms-of-authentication

Comment: Where did you get the idea to pass a `dict` in the first place?

Comment: When I printed out the `auth` value that requests does accept it looks like a dict. I was using the same format as what I saw. I did not know how to make the dict into an auth that's what prompted this question.

Comment: Would [this](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/) help you? If I read that changing your brackets from "{" to "(" could be enough to do the trick, otherwise maybe import HTTPBasicAuth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) accepts a tuple for basic auth. So instead of your `auth = {user:password}` it will work with `auth = (user, password)`

Comment: Thanks. When I tri that I get: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'`. Any idea what I can get around that?

Comment: We can't really tell you what authentication method the server you are sending this request to is asking for. the tuple works for basic auth. The point is: `requests` is accepting this, the problem is beyond it now.

Comment: The confluence server I'm sending to uses Kerberos. In my script I'm doing this: `from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth
    auth = get_login()
    auth = str(auth).replace('(','').replace('\'','').replace(',',':').replace(')','').replace(' ','')
    kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication="DISABLED",principal=auth)
    auth = kerberos_auth` and when the user types in his password that works. But when I pass it from arguments using argparse it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Fixed it with these lines: `user = options.user
            password = options.password
            auth = (user, password)
            auth = str(auth).replace('(','').replace('\'','').replace(',',':').replace(')','').replace(' ','')
            kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication="DISABLED",principal=auth)` thanks for your help!